# Protecting Data Access in Multi-Tenant Web API Application

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, multi-tenant

I have a Web API 2.2 app that I've been working on, where I'm trying to secure data access across tenants.

To make things simple, I was locking access to entities with a reusable where clause that took a user's auth token and then filtered their results:

```
// GET: odata/Contacts
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
        return db.Contacts.Where(_appContext.Helper.Expr_AppContactsFilter);
    }
```

Then, I was able to do the same thing to override how navigation properties worked like below:

```
// GET: odata/Contacts(5)/Owner
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Contact> GetOwner([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return db.Contacts.Where(m => m.ID == key).Where(_appContext.Helper.Expr_AppContactsFilter).SelectMany(m => m.OwnerContacts);
    }
```

So that when this query is executed (.../odata/Contacts(2)/Owner)  the result is empty, as it should be:

```
{ "odata.metadata":".../odata/$metadata#Contacts","value":[ ] }
```

However, if I try to expand the list of Contacts I have access to with the Owner property, or make things a little more complex and navigate up from another entity into Contacts and then Owners, I'm able to access an entity that may not be a part of my tenancy:

accessing via Contacts() - /odata/Contacts?$expand=Owner

```
{  
   "odata.metadata":".../odata/$metadata#Contacts",
   "value":[  
      {  
         "Owner":{  
            "ID":4,
            ...
            "Application_ID":2 //here we see the owner is not part of this tenant
         },
         "ID":2,
         "Owner_ID":4,
         "Application_ID":1,
        ...
      },
      {  
         "Owner":{  
            "ID":1,
            "FirstName":"System",
            "Application_ID":null, //here we see the owner is not part of this tenant
            ...
         },
         "ID":3,
         "FirstName":"Bruce",
         "Owner_ID":1,
         "Application_ID":1,
      }
   ]
}
```

and via 2 level navigation - .../odata/Websites(2)?$expand=Contact/Owner

```
{  
   "odata.metadata":".../odata/$metadata#Websites/@Element",
   "Contact":{  
      "Owner":{  
         ...
         "Application_ID":2,  //here we see the owner is not a part of this tenant
      },
      "ID":2,
      "FirstName":"Shawn",
      "MiddleName":"",
      "LastName":"Souto",
      "Organization":"SSI Design",
      "Owner_ID":4,
      ...
   },
   "ID":2,
   "URL":"http://www.example.com",
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to filter the $expand logic, or other odata parameters to keep access within the tenant?

Also, is there a better way to do this (that's still relatively simple) without entirely redoing all the API Controller logic?